# Custom sort ordered map with tuple as keys

Tags: c++, dictionary, key, tuples

Say I define my tuple as follows:

```
typedef tuple<string, string> bigram;
```

And my map maps tuples to integers:

```
map<bigram, int> mymap;
```

How can I custom my comparator so that `mymap` is sorted according to the alphabetical order of the first string in a `bigram`?

I'm thinking somewhere along the lines of

```
map<bigram, int, greater<bigrams[0]>> mymap;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First - alphabetical order means you want `less` rather than `greater`. Second, the default sort order for `tuple<string, string>` should just work for you. Note: the various suggestions  people are giving probably don't do what you want. They'd all compare `{"foo", "bar"}` and `{"foo", "baz"}` as equal when you probably want them to be treated as different objects. If you want reverse sorting, you should be able to do `map<bigram, int, std::greater<bigram>>` otherwise stick to simply `map<bigram, int>`.

For reference the definition of the comparison operators that come for free with tuple: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp

Answer (score 2):

If you want a correct comparator, you have to check every component of the tuple.

For me the good answer is :

```
    typedef std::tuple<std::string, std::string> bigrams;

    struct bigrams_comp {
        bool operator()(const bigrams& lhs, const bigrams& rhs) {
            if (std::get<0>(lhs) == std::get<0>(rhs)) {
                return std::get<1>(lhs) > std::get<1>(rhs);
            } else {
            return std::get<0>(lhs) > std::get<0>(rhs);
            }
        }
    };
```

Otherwise the binary search of the map will be false.

Tell me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Define a comparator either as a function or a function object and pass that:

```
bool comparator( const bigram& a, const bigram& b )
{
    ...
}
std::map<bigram, int, comparator> map;
```

The comparator should return true if the arguments are already ordered (a is before b).

Answer (score 1):

It can be implemented like this:

```
typedef std::tuple<std::string, std::string> bigrams;

struct bigrams_comp {
    bool operator()(const bigrams& lhs, const bigrams& rhs) {
        // return std::greater<std::string>()(std::get<0>(lhs), std::get<0>(rhs));
        return std::get<0>(lhs) > std::get<0>(rhs);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<bigrams, int, bigrams_comp> mymap;
}
```

Comment: Any reason for `std::greater`? Why not `std::get<0>(lhs) > std::get<0>(rhs)`?

Comment: @Rakete1111 because he uses greater in his question

Answer (score 0):

You used bigrams but defined bigram, does it a typo?

The compare function type must compare two Key type returns a bool value.

```
struct MyCompare
{
    bool operator()(const bigram &a, const bigram &b) 
    {
        return std::get<0>(a) > std::get<0>(b);
    }
};

map<bigram, int, MyCompare> mymap;
```